# Вытащить часть информации с сайта

Tags: java, android

И так, чтобы было понятнее я изъясню задачу.
Есть некий WEB сайт. Сразу на нем выводится логотип, после идут различные ссылки в блоке `<div class="link">***</div>` после этого на странице выводится **список статей**, после этого списка идут "ноги" сайта.
Вот мне нужно с помощью WebView вывести на экран только список статей, которые находятся в блоке `<div class="stat">***</div>`
Покуда я реализовал только сам компонент WebView который выводит весь сайт.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь в реализации данной цели. 
Возможно вопрос вам покажется глупым, я не очень давно в Android.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно спарсить инфу с сайта и уже ее выводить. Можно поспользоваться [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) или [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net).
Пример использования jsoup.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://link.com/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select(".stat");
Elements articles = newsHeadlines.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element article: articles) {
      String linkHref = link.attr("href");
      String linkText = link.text();
}
```

Сохраняешь данные как тебе угодно и из них формируешь страницу, которую показываешь пользователю.

Comment: я так понял ваш код выведет все что находится в блоке *stat* . Можете дать пример кода, с помощью которого я смогу вывести все это на экран?

Comment: Грубо говоря, да. Получает страницу, достает из нее все элементы с классом `stat`, из полученных элементов достает текст и сами ссылки. Я под андроид не пишу, но по первым же ссылкам попался такой пример.  `String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);`
 Т.е. собираешь нужные данные, из них генеришь html, который отдаешь в webview.